# Teams tab disappears

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing a teams app (tab). Use manifest like this (the app is available in a team, chat, and in a meeting)

```json
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://.....",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "context":[
        "channelTab",
        "privateChatTab",
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
     ]
    }
  ],
```

The problem is, when I add a tab to a MEETING, it disappears after a few seconds after being added (!!!) o_O. That is, I add the tab; the tab stays visible in the meeting for something like 5 seconds, and then it just disappears, and then the default meeting tab is activated.

Also, the app is not shown in the "add an app", but displayed in the generic list:

[image]

Is there some setting I'm missing? Should the application be **published** to behave normally in the meeting? When I add the same app to a chat, or to a team, everything works as expected. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems that "meetingChatTab" is missing in the context.  Please add "meetingChatTab" in the manifest and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like suggested above by @Meghana-MSFT, adding `meetingChatTab` solved the issue.
Found related note here:

https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2021/01/how-to-turn-a-teams-tab-into-a-in-meeting-side-bar/

> Gotcha! – There seems to be a bug at the moment, where an application needs to have the “meetingChatTab” context added, otherwise it won’t show up in the final Add a tab dialog. So, even if you don’t want your application to interact via the chat tab, it looks like you have to add it for now. This feels like a bug so I would also keep an eye on this as I would expect this requirement to be removed in the future.